# String of a filename used within a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, pattern-matching

I have a list of files:

```
name1andlast1.address
name2andlast2.address
name2andlast2.address
...
```

I want to create a bash script that use each *.address file + use files which names are strings of the *.address filename. The delimiter will be "and" (without the file extension), so I can use name#.list and last#.list

For example, **within a bash script** that run for **name1andlast1.address**, I would like to use a set of files (in another directory) called **name1.list** and **last1.list**:

```
grep "something" name1.list > output1
grep "something" last1.list > output2
grep "something" name1andlast1.address > output3
```

The order of using grep is not important. What is more important is how to use the filename (i.e name1andlast1.address) to input in my bash script name1.list and last1.list. I need to find a way to extract those bnames separate by “and”.  I need to find a way to do it iterative over multiple *.address files

Comment: Can you give a proper value for `name1andlast1.address`, so that what is the de-limiter we can use to use to split words `name1` and `last1`?

Comment: @Inian, thank! I have edited my post. The delimiter would be "and" but I also need to discard the file extension (.address)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do after you split the names. `name1.list` and `last1.list`

Comment: why did you grep them separately in such order? Should not all subitems be extracted from `name1andlast1.address` beforehand? Your question stays unclear

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have edited the last part of my question. I hope I make it clear now. Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you use 2 arguments? Like `myscript name1 last1` that would process `$1`, `$2` and `"${1}and${2}"`.

Answer (score 1):

> to find a way to extract those bnames separate by “and”. I need to
>   find a way to do it iterative over multiple *.address files

***bash*** solution:

```
for f in *.address; do 
    name_l=${f%and*}.list
    last_l=${f#*and}
    last_l=${last_l//.address/.list}
    # ... do futher search/processing with "$name_l" and "$last_l" 
done
```

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest! actually the **"$name_l"**  does not work but it works if I write **${f%and*}.list** directly. Maybe this is a naive question, but is there any way to make **last_l** in one line command?

Comment: @gusa10, welcome, *to make last_l in one line command* - nope. The less accurate case would use `sed`  which will fill the array with 2 items: `arr=($(sed -E 's/^(.*)and([^.]+).*/\1.list \2.list/' <<<"$f"))`

Comment: The less accurate case would be using `sed`  which will fill the array with 2 items: `arr=($(sed -E 's/^(.*)and([^.]+).*/\1.list \2.list/' <<<"$f"))`, where `${arr[0]}` is `name1.list` and `${arr[1]}` is `last1.list`. But I recommend to stay on bash approach

Comment: I was thinking on editing my files to I get as a filename **name1andlast1** only (without any extension). I know that to iterate over all folders i can use **for d in */** , but I dont know how to iterate over files. Most of the suggestions are done over files with extensions (i.e **for i in *.txt**). Do you know a way to iterate over files despite the extension (or no extension in my case). If I do it in this way, I can get **last_l** using your recommendation (**${f#*and}**)